# Appropriate word for smile

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, american-english, synonyms

I'm looking for an appropriate word for a certain kind of a smile.

> Are you in love with that girl' asked she with a grin on her face.

I have used the word *grin* but I guess *grin* is a broad smile.

The situation here is the girl who is asking the question is in love with the guy. But she hasn't told him yet. She heard from someone that he likes someone else. So the degree of smile is actually a small smile which doesn't reveal much.

Comment: Not what you asked, but would 'twinkle in her eye' work for you?

Comment: A wry grin perhaps.

Comment: Have you looked in a thesaurus? In any case, thank you for providing such a good context, this makes it much easier for users to answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ys i tried but couldn't get what i was really looking for..

Answer (score 2):

I think [*modest smile*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=modest+smile&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmodest%20smile%3B%2Cc0) would work well:

> Are you in love with that girl' she asked with a [*modest*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/modest) smile.

According to TFD it has the meanings:

> 1. Having or showing a moderate estimation of one's own talents, abilities, and value.
> 2. Having or proceeding from a disinclination to call attention to oneself; retiring or diffident. See Synonyms at shy1.
> 3. Observing conventional proprieties in speech, behavior, or dress.
> 4. Free from showiness or ostentation; unpretentious. See Synonyms at plain.
> 5. Moderate or limited in size, quantity, or range; not extreme: a modest price; a newspaper with a modest circulation.

By 5, it means "not large," which can mean small. "Not revealing much" may be captured by 4, particularly about herself as noted in 2.

Two other words to describe her smile might be [coy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coy) or [demure](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/demure).

Answer (score 1):

Are you in love with that girl, she asked with a *nervous* smile on her face.

She is uncertain of the answer and is not sure of his reaction, hence nervous. I would have said *hopeful* or *anticipatory* but they imply that the verdict would be in her favor.

Comment: dat sounds good...

Answer (score 0):

Sardonic:grimly mocking or cynical."stark  attempted a sardonic smile".
So I think"sardonic" smile is apt in this case because it also highlights the disapproving factor , if you follow other definitions.(from free dictionary: characterised by a scornful derision , bitter irony )

Comment: Sardonic has negative connotations, to describe the smile of someone in love as such sounds eery and almost menacing.

Comment: Yeah,here the smile has negative connotations(she obviously is smiling disapprovingly). I disagree about menacing and eerie though.

Comment: But sardonic does not convey a "small smile".

Answer (score 0):

One way (similar to davidgo's comment) would be to avoid naming the smile at all, and concentrate on the adjectives describing the smile itself, then you have much more flexibility:

'Are you in love with that girl ?', she asked with a inquisitive / teasing, shy smile.

And/Or even describe her body language.. 'tilting her head to the side..' to imply awkwardness.

Answer (score 0):

If she was in love with the guy, smiling would not be easy. I would write,

> "Are you in love with that girl?", she asked with a forced smile.

or,

> "Are you in love with that girl?", she asked, trying to bring out a smile.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in love with that girl?

- She asked **coyly** [1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coy)
- She asked **sweetly** [2](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweetly?show=0&t=1389665281)
- She smiled **nervously** [3](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nervously)
- She smiled **hesitantly** [4](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hesitantly)
- She queried **demurely** [5](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demurely)
- She queried **timidly** with a smile [6](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/timidly)
- She gently probed with the **hint of a smile** [7](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hint)

Answer (score -1):

"Are you in love with that girl?" she asked with a tentative smile.