# Adverb for particular kind of smile

Tags: vocabulary, adverbs

Similar to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145772/appropriate-word-for-smile), I'm looking for a word to describe a particular kind of smile.

It's the kind of smile I smile when I receive a sweet message from the girl I love, and just can't help beaming. The phrase which goes through my mind is 'smiling like a fool', but I somehow think there might be a more precise adverb (e.g. smiling **sheepishly**, which I don't think quite fits).

"I catch myself smiling ____ when I read her texts."

Which adverb fits best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He smiled **soppily** at his girlfriend.

> **soppy**:
>
> If you describe someone or something as soppy, you mean that they are
>   foolishly sentimental. [British, informal]
>
> *He's constantly on the phone to his girlfriend being soppy.*
>
> *She loves soppy love stories, old films, that sort of thing.*
>
> [COBUILD Advanced English
>   Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/soppy)

Answer (score 1):

euphorically?

euphoric - characterized by or feeling intense excitement and happiness

enraptured [smile] - filled with great pleasure or joy

**Edit to add sources:**

euphoric is from:  https://kathysteinemann.com/Musings/smiles/

'enrapture' - not sure. May have looked for synonyms of euphoric and it was just in search results.

Answer (score 0):

Will **dopily** work for you?

Dopey: *Silly; foolish*

[THEFREEDICTIONARY.COM meaning for Dopey](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dopily)

There's also a clip-art in the said webpage. See if it(the grin) matches yours for accuracy.